# Viewmodel boolean not set

Tags: java, android, kotlin

```
private void enableWidget(final Context context) {
  if (featureFlagDisposable != null) {
    featureFlagDisposable.dispose();
  }
  featureFlagDisposable = Single.fromCallable(() -> {
    featureFlagsConnector = FeatureFlagsConnector.getInstance(context);
    featureFlagsConnector.blockingFetchFeatureFlags();
    return featureFlagsConnector.isFeatureFlagEnabled(FeatureFlagName.WIDGET_FLAG.toString());
  }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
          .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
          .subscribe(this::initViewModel);
}

private void initViewModel(boolean isFeatureFlagEnabled) {
  if (isFeatureFlagEnabled) {
    if (viewModel == null) {
      viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ViewModel.class);
      viewModel.getShowWidget().observe(this, this::setWidgetVisibility);
      
      viewModel.setSchedulingEnabled(true);
    }

    viewModel.setSchedulingEnabled(true);
  } else if (viewModel != null) {
    viewModel.getShowWidget().removeObservers(this);
    viewModel = null;
    setWidgetVisibility(false); // don't show rd widget
  }
}
```

```
class ViewModel(app: Application) : AndroidViewModel(app) {
   
    var schedulingEnabled: Boolean = false

    init {
        DataStore.initialize(getApplication())
        ServicesRxJava2.init(getApplication())

        val repository = ServicesRxJava2.getInstance().repository
        observeLoggedEmployee()
    }

   ...
}
```

In the above code, I am setting the setSchedulingEnabled to true. However in the viewModel boolean continues to remain false. One thing is that this is in the parent Activity which is in Java. The ViewModel class is written in Kotlin. Not sure if that is causing any issue.

I have explicitly set the boolean here to true but viewmodel does not have it set at all. Why is this happening?

Comment: Can you please share your ViewModel code where this flag is being set

Comment: yes, I just added.

Comment: I simplified my viewmodel but schedulingEnabled is a simple boolean. Since its a kotlin we dont need any setters

Comment: Maybe it is happening because you null out your `viewModel` in the `else-if` block. What I can gather from your `initViewModel` code is that, whenever an instance of `viewModel` exists, the `schedulingEnabled` flag is set to `true`, otherwise it is false(which is the default).